# Dynamically replacing parameters in URI

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, uri, dotnet-httpclient

I have written a utility class function that takes in a URI and an ID that creates a HTTPClient using the provided URI.

```
    private async Task<T> GetUriScopedResource<T>(string uri, int id)
    {
        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient(_baseUri);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseUri);
        var result = await client.GetAsync($"{uri}{id}");
        return await DeserialiseContentAsync<T>(result);
    }
```

The above is currently set up to expect the dynamic parameter to be at the end of the uri.

Eg.

```
"api/Employee/{id}"
```

However my requirements have changed and I have a controller method that looks like the following:

```
"api/Employee/{id}/accounts"
```

How can I modify

```
client.GetAsync($"{relativeUri}{id}");
```

to dynamically replace the {X} for any URI provided? Could URIBuilder achieve this desired functionality?

Any help would be great!

Comment: Also thinking about it, it may need to handle multiple parameters being passed in to the function. For example the URI could be "api/Employee/{id}/accountsettings/{accountId}"

Comment: if the uri is always changing you will have to build this manually, maybe predefined urls with `{0)` `{1}` in it and use string.Format to populate them

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for nice, structured URL building, [Flurl](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-url/) (disclaimer: I'm the author) could be helpful. It has a static `Url.Combine` method which, similar to `Path.Combine` for files, ensure 1 and only 1 separator character between segments:

```
Url.Combine(_baseUri, relativeUri, id, "accounts")
```

The [core Flurl package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl/) is very small and dependency-free.

[Flurl.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl.Http/) adds fluent HTTP, Json.NET (de)serialization, testing features, and smart `HttpClient` instance management to the mix. Your example would look like this:

```
private Task<T> GetUriScopedResource<T>(string uri, int id)
{
    return _baseUri
        .AppendPathSegments(uri, id, "accounts")
        .GetJsonAsync<T>();
}
```

`AppendPathSegments` basically gives you `Url.Combine` as a fluent extension method off `string`.